# How to search for specific files recursively, create folder and move file to it?

Tags: powershell

How can I search for a specific file extension recursively through out the entire directory structure, for each file/extension found create a folder at the file location using each file's name, and move the file/s to its own folder (that matches the files name)?

Thank you @Alex_P: The following code creates only one folder, and moves ALL the files found into this folder. Is there a way to make it create a folder for each item and then move each item to its corresponding folder. Appreciate your help.

```
  $_ = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\3\ML\300000-310000S\302355\OLn2" -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.MCX-5' })
    
    ForEach-Object {

  New-Item -Path $_[0].PSParentPath -Name $_[0].BaseName -ItemType Directory

$newpath = Join-Path -Path $_[0].PSParentPath -ChildPath $_[0].BaseName
Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $newpath -Force

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` returns `System.IO.FileInfo` objects. You can use their property 'Extension' to filter for file extensions.

This example will give you all PDF files:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path .\Documents\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.pdf' }
```

In order to move the files you can use some other, useful properties of the object. `.PSParentPath` gives you the path up to the directory of your object. `.BaseName` gives you the file name, excluding the extension.

```
New-Item -Path $files[0].PSParentPath -Name $files[0].BaseName -ItemType Directory
```

Now, in order to move your item, you need to concatenate your path with your new directory and then you can move the item to your new directory. `.Fullname` gives you the full path of the object.

```
$newpath = Join-Path -Path $files[0].PSParentPath -ChildPath $files[0].BaseName
Move-Item -Path $files[0].FullName -Destination $newpath
```

In my case, I only moved one item but you need to add these to your `foreach` loop.

Comment: A correction: there can be `DirectoryInfo` objects interspersed if you don't specify the `-File` switch.

Comment: @Alex_P, Appreciate so much your help! tried your code hopefully in the correct manner; however, my loop is not picking up all the files in the folders... it only pick one file and perform the operations correctly on it alone.

Comment: @samgoto, Instead of `$files[0]` use `$_`.

Comment: @Alex_P appreciate your assistance, just have to figure out how to make a folder per file found and then move it to its corresponding folder...

Comment: @samgoto, you loop through all files in the variable `$files`. In the loop you write `New-Item -Path $_.PSParentPath -Name $_.BaseName -ItemType Directory` plus the `Join-Path` command and the `Move-Item` command. In all three cases you need to replace `$files[0]` with `$_` and it should work.