# Powershell Loop through folder move file, create directory if doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

Good Afternoon,

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I have been struggling with it, also still very new to Powershell.

I have a network mapped folder `Z:\Test`.

Under `Z:\Test` is multiple subfolders with the same structure.  I need to loop through all of the subfolders and move all PDF files if they exist in a specific location.

`Z:\Test\1\Work\PDF\*.PDF` - then move
`Z:\Test\2\Work\PDF\*.PDF` - Move So on and so on.

I have tried the following, but like I said I have been struggling with it.  Thanks any help

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\temp\*\Work -File -Include "*.PDF" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Force -Destination Y:\Temp\*\Work
```

Comment: I formated your post to ease the readability a bit.

Comment: How to know which file should goes into which folder? I assume *.pdf means all pdf files, but how do you want to split them up, or should all PDF files go into the same folder?

Comment: If the file exists in the folder on the Z:\ then it needs to be copied to Y:\
for example Z:\1\Work\PDF\1.pdf  That should copy to Y:\1\Work\PDF\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create directory if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906170/create-directory-if-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: Also, I wrote an answer on this question which might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797873/how-to-search-for-specific-files-recursively-create-folder-and-move-file-to-it/62798284#62798284

Regarding your last comment, what problem do you actually get when trying to copy the files? Any errors?

Comment: I think I can create the directory in the script I don't think that part is difficult.  It's the looping through the folders in the source and copying only the files in the specific subdirectory that is giving me the problems,
I should have also said that there are other folders under Z:\Test\1\ that may contain PDF.  I do not wish to have those copied only from the specific path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\Temp\*\Work -File -Include "*.PDF" -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination Y:\Temp\*\Work -Force
}
```

Comment: Ok, TY I will attempt your suggestion.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JasonSteffens, in the loop you can filter the files in an if-statement for example.